# Customize WSAT in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, security, wsat

Has anyone ever customized the website admin tool in ASP.Net?  I would like to add some fields when ceating a user and keep it all in one place.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W£as a tumbleweed :)  Not sure if anyone has done this or not.  I've managed to rip out the table sthat are not used and create a few views in MVC to allow Intranet\Internet MVC applications,  It's working well.

If anyone requires anything like this I'm happy to help.